# Entity Framework 1 to 0 or 1 relationship configuration

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have this class

```
public class Parent
{
  [Key]
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public virtual Child Child { get; set; }
}
```

and a child class

```
public class Child
{
  [Key]
  [ForeignKey]
  public int ParentId { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

The relation is such that a parent can have either 0 or 1 child. I've checked SO and found two solutions.

```
modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ParentChildMap());

// solution 1
class ParentChildMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Child>
{
    public ParentChildMap()
    {
        HasRequired(t => t.Parent).
            WithRequiredDependent(t => t.Child);    
    }
}

// solution 2
class ParentChildMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Child>
{
    public ParentChildMap()
    {
         HasOptional(c => c.Parent)
            .WithRequired(c => c.Child);
    }
}
```

*And the thing is, they are both working*! But the problem is, **I am not sure which one is correct.** Which one is providing me the mapping that one parent can have only 0 or 1 child. And then, what is the other one saying?

Comment: This doesn't look right at all, actually. Why does Child have a reference to Parent? It shouldn't need it, except for ParentId. The Variable shouldn't be needed. By looking at the code it seems what you would want is `HasOptional(c => c.Child).WithRequired(c => c.Parent);` Also, Child should have it's own Id that is the primary key, and the ParentId should be a foreign key.

Comment: You shouldn't have `ParentId` as a `[Key]` in your `Child` class, you want to create another `Id` property on your `Child` class, and for `ParentId` property use `[ForeignKey]` attribute instead. As for your `EntityTypeConfiguration<Child>` you want `HasRequired(t => t.Parent)`

Comment: *I am not sure which one is correct* -- The method names (containing "Optional", "Required") should give you a strong hint. Both solutions are incorrect.

Comment: omg _thank you_ for using `Parent` and `Child` and not DMATRFPR and DMATRFPR_FUPAFPLS or some such nonsense like all of the rest of the examples on this topic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let add the related entities to the desired relationship along with their cardinality:

**Parent 1 <--> 0..1 Child**

You can read it this way:

(1) **--> 0..1 Child** means that each Parent can have 0 or 1 Child, or in other words, the `Child` property of the `Parent` entity is **optional**

(2) **Parent 1 <--** means that each Child always have 1 Parent, or in other words, the `Parent` property of the `Child` entity is **required**.

The fluent configuration which corresponds to the above from `Child` side is:

```
HasRequired(c => c.Parent).WithOptional(p => p.Child);
```

or alternatively from `Parent` side:

```
HasOptional(p => p.Child).WithRequired(c => c.Parent);
```

These two are the correct ones and fully equivalent - you can use one or the another depending of whether you start the configuration from `Child` (as in your sample) or from `Parent`. To avoid discrepancies, never do both.

*Why both your current solutions are incorrect?*

Because:

(solution 1)

```
HasRequired(t => t.Parent).WithRequiredDependent(t => t.Child);
```

represents **Parent 1 <--> 1 Child**  relationship (parent must have always 1 child).

(solution 2)

```
HasOptional(c => c.Parent).WithRequired(c => c.Child);
```

represents **Parent 0..1 <--> 1 Child** relationship (child can have 0 or 1 parent, parent must have always 1 child), i.e. the opposite of what you want.

Comment: How do you define Child's Foreign key, if it's Foreign key property doesn't follow  EF naming convention ?
Is it possible using fluent syntax or do you _need_ to use annotation for that ?

Comment: @Riva See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50011305/entity-framework-one-to-one-referentialconstraint-is-mapped-to-a-store-gener/50054609#50054609

Answer (score 4):

> And the thing is, they are both working! But the problem is, I am not
>   sure which one is correct?

Yes! your both approach is incorrect (Credit goes to Ivan Stoev). Because:

Your solution 1 :

```
HasRequired(t => t.Parent).WithRequiredDependent(t => t.Child);
```

represents Parent 1 <--> 1 Child relationship (parent must have always 1 child).

Your solution 2:

```
HasOptional(c => c.Parent).WithRequired(c => c.Child);
```

represents Parent 0..1 <--> 1 Child relationship (child can have 0 or 1 parent, parent must have always 1 child), i.e. the opposite of what you want.

Your Fluent API should be as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>()
                .HasOptional(p => p.Child) // Mark Child property optional in Parent entity
                .WithRequired(c => c.Parent); // mark Parent property as required in Child entity. Cannot save Child without Parent
```

Moreover you can also configure One-to-One or One-to-Zero relationship with Data Annotation as follows:

Child class should be as follows:

```
public class Child
{
  [Key,ForeignKey("Parent")]
  public int ParentId { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: No! How?? Parent primary key is also primary key in child..Can a table have duplicate primary key??Absolutely No..

Comment: What he wants is a one to one or zero relationship

Comment: Other children could also have the same parent key, which will result in a one to zero or many!!!

Comment: You are getting things wrong..My code is for one-to-one or one-to-zero relationship..what he exactly wants..

Comment: @Owuor, For further more clarification you can check Entity Framework official documentation

Comment: As you have edited your code, to show the parent having one child, now your code is correct, Without defining the child relationship in the parent, your code would have allowed for different children to reference/have a relationship with one/the same parent.

Comment: Still downvoted.This answer don't clarify what he did wrong and why, the bit i like is suggesting a more common way to configure the entities and a more beatiful (imo) one (both not asked)...

Comment: @L. Trabacchin, got it..Answer has been correct from Ivan Stoev Answers's

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to decorate `ForeignKey` attribute. if you want to have a 1 to 0 relation, a side of relation must be optional (ex: HasOptional), like the following code:

```
public class Parent
{
   [Key]
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public virtual Child Child { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
   [Key]
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
}



public class ParentMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Parent>
{
    public ParentMap ()
    {
        HasOptional(t => t.Child).WithRequired(t => t.Parent);
    }
}
```

now when you add a new parent to the database does not need to add a child because it is optional but when you want to add a new child to the database the child `Id` must equal with parent `Id`.