# Entity Framework - One-to-One - ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have what should be a simple one-to-one relationship to create within EF. But I'm receiving the following error when I try to insert:

> ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column. Column:
>   'ACCOUNT_ID'.

**Console App example:**

```
namespace EF_ConsoleApp_Test
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var account = new Account
            {
                AccountNumber = "00123456",
                CustomerValue = new Customer { FirstName = "Joe" }
            };

            using (var db = new MainContext())
            {
                db.Accounts.Add(account);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    [Table("CUSTOMERS")]
    public class Customer
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("CUSTOMER_ID")]
        public int? Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Column("FIRST_NAME")]
        [StringLength(45)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public virtual Account Account { get; set; }

        public Customer() { }
    }

    [Serializable]
    [Table("ACCOUNTS")]
    public class Account
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Column("ACCOUNT_ID")]
        public int? Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Column("ACCOUNT_NUMBER")]
        [Display(Name = "Account Number")]
        [StringLength(16)]
        public string AccountNumber { get; set; }

        [Column("CUSTOMER_ID")]
        public int? CustomerId { get; set; }

        public virtual Customer CustomerValue { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Default Constructor
        /// </summary>
        public Account() { }
    }

    internal class MainContext : DbContext
    {
        internal MainContext() : base("name=DB.Context")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<MainContext>(null);
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }

        public virtual DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            // Configure FK
            modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
                .HasRequired(c => c.Account)
                .WithRequiredPrincipal(a => a.CustomerValue);

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
}
```

**Database Table Create statements:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CUSTOMERS](
    [CUSTOMER_ID] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FIRST_NAME] [varchar](45) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_CUSTOMERS] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CUSTOMER_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ACCOUNTS](
    [ACCOUNT_ID] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CUSTOMER_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ACCOUNT_NUMBER] [varchar](16) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ACCOUNTS] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ACCOUNT_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ACCOUNTS]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ACCOUNTS_CUSTOMERS] FOREIGN KEY([CUSTOMER_ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[CUSTOMERS] ([CUSTOMER_ID])
GO
```

**App.config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1" />
  </startup>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DB.Context"
         connectionString="data source=localdb;initial catalog=EF_TEST;Integrated Security=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework;Connection Timeout=30;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>

</configuration>
```

What do I need to change to make this work?

**Notes:**

- I'm using EF 6.2 and .NET 4.7.1.
- I inherited this database schema and the one-to-one relationship cannot be changed.
- I'm trying to avoiding explicitly creating a transaction by only calling SaveChanges() once opposed to wrapping a separate call to create Customer first, then Account.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By convention EF6 represents the one-to-one relationships using the so called [Shared Primary Key Association](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-3-shared-primary-key-associations), where the PK of the dependent entity also serves as FK to the principal entity.

In your case, it considers `Account.Id` to be the FK to `Customer`, and since it's auto-generated, you get the exception in question.

The additional problem is that EF6 does not support one-to-one relationship with explicit FK property (there is no `HasForeignKey` fluent API similar to one-to-many relationships).

So you need to remove the `AccountId` property from the model and leave only the navigation property. Also, although not strongly necessary, it would be good to follow the naming conventions and just call it `Account` rather than `AccountValue`.

In other words, replace

```
[Column("CUSTOMER_ID")]
public int? CustomerId { get; set; }

public virtual Customer CustomerValue { get; set; }
```

with

```
public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
```

The FK column name can be specified using the `MapKey` fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
    .HasRequired(c => c.Account)
    .WithRequiredPrincipal(a => a.Customer)
    .Map(m => m.MapKey("CUSTOMER_ID")); // <--
```

And you are done.

Now the following correctly inserts first a new `Customer` and then a new `Account` referencing it:

```
var account = new Account
{
    AccountNumber = "00123456",
    Customer = new Customer { FirstName = "Joe" }
};
db.Accounts.Add(account);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: You are welcome. In EF Core one-to-one support is much better. But it has it's own drawbacks. No full happiness :)

Comment: Hi @Ivan, I created a related question for an error on udpates:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50141979/ef-one-to-one-update-fails